# CLR/System.IO.FileLoadException: “Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089”

Tags: c#, google-maps, visual-studio-code, coreclr

I have this exception generated in my project in Visual Studio Code:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.IO.FileLoadException An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Infrastructure.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)' at GoogleMaps.LocationServices.GoogleLocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(String address) at FrequentFlyer.Infrastructure.Services.GoogleMapsService.GetLatLongAsync(AddressData city) in d:\C#\FrequentFlyer\FrequentFlyer.Infrastructure\Services\GoogleMapsService.cs:line 20 at FrequentFlyer.Infrastructure.Services.NodeProvider..ctor(IMemoryCache cache, IGoogleMapsService googleMapsService) in d:\C#\FrequentFlyer\FrequentFlyer.Infrastructure\Services\NodeProvider.cs:line 83 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()

---

This exception shows in third line:

```
public double[] GetLatLongAsync(AddressData city)
{
    var latlong = _googleLocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(city);
    var latitude = latlong.Latitude;
    var longitide = latlong.Longitude;
    double[] coordinates = {latitude, longitide};

    return coordinates;
}
```

---

I think the problem is in my .csproj file. I've got almost the same problem earlier (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'), but when I installed package: "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1", the problem was gone. Now it shows again and I can't handle it.

I use .NET Standard1.6, but package: GoogleMaps.LocationServices is only compatible with .NET Framework 4.0, so my .csproj is ugly (in my opinion).

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
    <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);net40</PackageTargetFallback>
    <AssemblyName>Infrastructure</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Infrastructure</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../FrequentFlyer.Core/FrequentFlyer.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="GoogleMaps.LocationServices" Version="1.2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDb.Driver" Version="2.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.01" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging " Version="1.0.0-rtm-beta5 " />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Device.Location.Portable" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Mongo\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What is wrong and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please add  your "GetLatLongFromAddress" Method?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method comes from: https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/blob/master/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/GoogleLocationService.cs. It starts at line 210.